# not able to understand output of regexp in tcl

Tags: tcl

Please explain the output of this tcl command , i am 
not getting the result .

```
on tclsh      
set line = "Clock Domain:               clk"     
regexp {Clock Domain:\s*(.+)} $line tmp1 Pnr_clk
```

```
$tmp1 = "Clock Domain:               clk"     
$Pnr_clk = clk
```

How this value is assigned

Answer (score 1):

The Tcl `regexp` command is documented to assign the submatches to the variables whose names you provide. The first such variable you give is `tmp1`, which gets the whole string that the overall RE matched (which might be a substring of the overall input string; Tcl's RE engine does not anchor matches by default). The second such variable is `Pnr_clk`, which gets what the first parenthesized sub-RE matches, which in this case is `clk` because the `\s*` before the parenthesis greedily consumed the whitespace after `Clock Domain:`.